# compiler not recognizing methods defined outside the class declaration

Tags: c++, function, class

new to c++.Im stuck with a question here, i made a bank account program which has functions like withdraw() and deposit() defined in a class called 'account'.So, i defined my class in a different file(account.h) also i defined withdraw() inside the class itself but defined the deposit() function outside the class in 'account.cpp' file.When i compile it i get  the following error -
`undefined reference to 'account::deposit(int)'`
I'm not an expert but i think it doesn't recognize that i defined the define() function int account.cpp.Also i use vscode (idk if that helps).

here is the code-
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "account.h"

int main()
{
    account Ajay_bank;

    if (Ajay_bank.withdraw(1000))
    {
        std::cout << "withdraw successful\n";

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "withdraw failed";
    }

    if (Ajay_bank.deposit(2000))
        std::cout << "Deposit successful";
    else
        std::cout << "[error - NET404]:try again later";


}
```

account.cpp-

```
#include "account.h"


bool account::deposit (int amount)
{
    balance += amount;
    return true;
}
```

account.h-

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H
#define _ACCOUNT_H

#include <string>

class account
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int balance {200};
    int credit_score {};
public:
    bool withdraw (int amount)
    {
        if (balance - amount >= 0)
        {
            balance -= amount;
            return true;
        }

        else
            return false;

    }
    bool deposit (int amount);

};

#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to compile and link account.cpp, it's doesn't happen automatically. Since you are using vscode, you need to create a project (if you haven't already) and add the two files main.cpp and account.cpp to that project,

Comment: Please show your exact compile command and error.

Comment: What is your compile code?

Comment: @john thanks for quick response, im new to c++ so can you please explain in detail how do i link account.cpp ??

Comment: @kaylum i use vscode and i use the keyboard short cut `ctrl` + `shift` + `b` to compile.And if you want the complete error log then here it is - `
C:\Users\KAKSHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBOrWHG.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/Kakshipth/Documents/coding/cpp/logical/oop/account/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `account::deposit(int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`

Comment: I'm not a VS code user so can't help you with that. But you should add that info into your question. Sounds like your project is not set up correctly to compile and link all the files.

Comment: @kaylum thanks anyway.I did add the that info in the question `Also i use vscode (idk if that helps).`.May i know which ide you use ??

Comment: @Kakshipth I'm not very familiar with vscode, I've seen enough of it here that I would not recommend it for beginners. Anyway as soon as you move beyond a single file you must create a project and add the files you have to the project. How precisely you do that I'm not sure,

Comment: @Kakshipth If you are on Windows I would recommend the community edition of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While compiling more than source file (.cpp) you should compile with that files.

```
g++ main.cpp account.cpp -o main
```

then run it like:

```
./main
```

If you try with that command you can run successfully

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked but dont you think its gonna be a bit tedious to enter all the file names as my project grows bigger?Is there any alternative way??

Comment: @Kakshipth you can use makefile extension in vs code. Source: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adriano-markovic.c-cpp-makefile-project